# snowflake - Order by not sorting correctly

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running a query in snowflake with a group by and order by clause and I notice that it is not ordering the first column in ascending order

`select distinct columnA from table order by columnA`

```
ColumnA
------------ + 
AMP 1
AMP 2
Aluminum
Apple
```

In the example, Aluminum should be the first row however, it falls in the third. Seems to me that there is an uppercase and lowercase prioritization in sorting. How will I be able to make row 3 be the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upper caps rank above lower caps.

This will sort then irrespective of capitalization:

```sql
with data as (select * from table(split_to_table('AMP 1
AMP 2
Aluminum
Apple', '\n')))

select distinct value
from data
order by lower(value);
```